# displaying a single row of data in php using pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
<?php 

if (!empty($_POST['modify']) && !empty($_POST['input']) && !empty($_POST['choose']))  {
  $val=$_POST['modify'];
  $input=$_POST['input'];
  echo"<table border=6><tr><th>id_etu</th>
  <th>Nom</th><th>Prénom</th><th>email</th>
  <th>mot de passe</th><th>Année</th></tr>";

   $sql= "SELECT * FROM etudiant WHERE '$val'='$input'"; 
   $sth=$conn->query($sql);
   $res= $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  foreach($res as $row){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$row['id_etu']."</td>"; 
    echo "<td>".$row['nom']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['prenom']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['email']."</td>"; 
    echo "<td>".$row['motdepasse']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['annee']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
  }
}
?>
```

Hey everyone, i'm still a beginner in php and using the PDO statement, and right now i'm having trouble displaying a single row of data on a php page. just to put you more in the context.
i have first a form where i choose the field by which i wanna display the row then a input where i type the value of the field then a submit button to send the form, then as a result i should get a table with one row, but instead i get the entire content of the table in the database. Help PLease.

Comment: `'$val'='$input'` So you'll either get everything or nothing. You don't limit anything in the table.

Comment: man, you need to sanitise your input, read about prepared statements with parameters in PDO first.

Comment: @JonStirling the problem is that the user is suppose to choose the field and type the value, how can i solve this

Comment: Your use of single quotes means you're doing a string comparison of 2 literal string, not of a string and a column.

Comment: Also, extending on @Deus777 comment, if you're passing the column to filter by in POST, you should validate it against a whitelist of allowed values.

Comment: the code is also vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries. PDO makes this really quite easy.

Comment: @YvonneStyles go and learn when to use `query()` and when to use `prepare()` in PDO